# discord.py tasks.loop() sending runtime error : no running event loop

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am trying to make my bot send a message in a particular channel hourly using the discord.ext's tasks. Here's the buggy piece of code

```
@tasks.loop(hours = 1)
async def remindstudy():
  await bot.wait_until_ready()
  channel = bot.get_channel(1038719402658517054)
  await channel.send("check")
remindstudy.start()
```

This is supposed to send the message "check" every hour but instead throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 137, in <module>
    remindstudy.start()
 File "/home/runner/main-bore-ho-raha-hoon/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 398, in start
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop

sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

What is going wrong? I copied this code snippet from another old bot of mine, it is still running perfectly fine, but this bot won't run

Answer (score 1):

The `task.start` method is expected to be called in an async function (coroutine), like in `setup_hook`, after the 2.0 update.

```py
async def setup_hook():
    remindstudy.start()
bot.setup_hook = setup_hook

@tasks.loop(hours = 1)
async def remindstudy():
  await bot.wait_until_ready()
  channel = bot.get_channel(1038719402658517054)
  await channel.send("check")
```

See this [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py#L13-L25).